# MongoDB in PHP - How do I insert items into an array in a collection?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, database, nosql

This has to be easy, but i can't seem to figure it out... Let say i had a collection `users` and this is the first item in the collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d8653c027d02a6437bc89ca"), 
    "name" : "Oscar Godson", 
    "email" : "oscargodson@xxx.com", 
    "password" : "xxxxxx", 
    "tasks" : [
    {
        "task" : "pick up stuff",
        "comment" : "the one stuff over there"
    },
    {
        "task" : "do more stuff",
        "comment" : "lots and lots of stuff"
    }
] }
```

How with the PHP driver for MongoDB would I then go and add another "task" to the "tasks" array in this item in a collection

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use Mongo's `$push` operation:

```
$new_task = array(
  "task" => "do even more stuff",
  "comment" => "this is the new task added"
);
$collection->update(
  array("_id" => ObjectId("4d8653c027d02a6437bc89ca")), 
  array('$push' => array("tasks" => $new_task))
);
```

Comment: The question should be... How do I add items to an array in an existing document?  Inserting a document with an array is not done with a $push because a $push is an update operator.  Do you know how that is done with the newer version of the php MongoDB API?