# insert json object to mongodb array field from php

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

I am writing a php script to insert a json object to an array field of a mongodb document . Specifically in the mongodb doc I want to push  an object in the format of `{'user': usr , 'commented':comment}` to the field `'comments':[]` in a mongodb doc . The problem is how to create this json object using php as this is my first time trying this .

This is what I have so far :

```
//find the correct item 
     $review  = array(
        "user"=>$usr,
        "comment"=>$comm,
        "rated"=>$rated
      ); 
    
    $productCollection->updateOne(array('id'=>$itmID),
       array('$push'=>array('comments'=>$review))
      );
```

Comment: I don't know if you spent any time researching because there is no proof of research in your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40081178/2943403 ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42299250/2943403 ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/40425533/2943403 ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/38545593/2943403 ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42384537/2943403 ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5370925/2943403 ?

Comment: If any of these resolve your question, then an answer is unnecessary.

Comment: @mickmackusa I  changed my code above but still no results

Comment: @mickmackusa No my friend none helped . I want the similar result as your last link